# Defining a struct as a global variable

Tags: c, pointers, struct, global

I am trying to define a pointer to a `struct` as a global variable and access the value of its variables in different functions. But I realized that the values are cleared after the next function call. Am I doing something wrong?

```
struct St {
  double* varDouble;
};

struct St* StGlobal;

void Fun1(){

 double initDouble[2][1] = {{1},{2}};

 StGlobal = (struct St*)malloc(sizeof(struct St));
 StGlobal->varDouble = *initDouble;
};

void Func2(){
 for (i =0;i<2;i++){
    printf("%d\n", StGlobal->varDouble);
   } 
};

int main(){
Func1();
Func2();  // value of StGlobal->varDouble is no longer what was assigned to it in Func1
};
```

Comment: Why make it a pointer? And more importantly, where is `varDouble` pointing to after calling `Fun1()`? Is that safe?

Comment: Actually I am trying to first initialize the variables of the struct in a function and then use the values in a different function. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Something like `void Func2()` is not a correct prototype-style declarator. You should use the correct form. This is C, not C++!

Comment: And do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void Fun1(){

 double initDouble[2][1] = {{1},{2}};

 StGlobal = (struct St*)malloc(sizeof(struct St));
 // OK. StGlobal points to a memory that was returned by malloc.
 // The memory will be valid after the function returns.

 StGlobal->varDouble = *initDouble;
 // Not OK. initDouble is a local 2D array. *initDouble is a pointer 
 // that is valid as long as initDouble is in scope. When the function
 // returns the pointer is not valid.
};
```

And

```
void Func2(){
 for (i =0;i<2;i++){
    printf("%d\n", StGlobal->varDouble);
    // StGlobal->varDouble is dangling pointer.
    // Also, you are printing a pointer using %d. ???
    // If you try to access the pointer here, the program will exhibit
    // undefined behavior since it is a dangling pointer.
   } 
};
```

After you allocate memory for `StGlobal`, you'll have to:

1. Allocate memory for `StGlobal->varDouble` also using `malloc`, or
2. Assign it to some other pointer that will be valid after the function returns.

Also. Don't cast the return value of `malloc` in C. See [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

**Additional info**

You can force MSVC to treat a file as a C program file by setting a compiler option. In VS2008, I can do that in the following dialog box.

[image]

There is probably a similar way to change the setting in MSVC 2010.

Comment: @Olaf, I thought of that but did not follow through since I used the OP's code to point out the issues.

Comment: @Olaf and @R Sahu thank you very much for your answers! I am building my code as C, but I still get this error when I don't cast malloc: a value of type void cannot be assigned to an entity of type St*.

Comment: @Shaga, what compiler and version are you using?

Comment: I am pretty new to C. how can I check the compiler version? I am using VS 2010 on a windows machine.

Comment: The compiler is most likely compiling the file as a C++ file, not C file. You can force the compiler to treat it as a C file by changing a command line option.

Comment: I agree with R.Sahu. A C compiler **must not** complain when assigning a `void *` to any other pointer. Even VC does not, although this compiler is know not to be standard-compliant since at least 16 years.

Comment: Well, I made sure that I am compiling as C by setting "Compile As" to "Compile as C Code (/TC)" in properties->C/C++->Advanced. And also renaming my files from .cpp to .c. I am not sure what else I should do to force the compiler to build as C.

Comment: It should be enough to just save the source file with the `.c` extension.  Then the module would be compiled using the C compiler.